# try to make drag drop using xml loading image from external folder image loaded, but when try to drag, error appears in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make drag drop using xml loading image from external folder image loaded, but when try to drag, error appears in AS3

```
public function startDragging(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //var ob_ldr = assets[evt.target.name]. @ OBJECT;
            var ob_ldr = Loader(evt.target.loader);
            ob_ldr.startDrag(true);

            /*var theImage:Bitmap = evt.currentTarget.content as Bitmap;
            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            mc.addChild(theImage);
                        mc.startDrag();*/
            //  theImage.star
            // assign properties and listeners to the MovieClip here

            //base.addChild(mc);

            //var obj_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            //obj_mc = MovieClip(ob_ldr)
            //trace("ob_ldr::"+mc.name);
            //startDrag(true);
            //trace(typeof(ob_ldr));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty much all wrong :

```
public function startDragging(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //var ob_ldr = assets[evt.target.name]. @ OBJECT;
            var ob_ldr = Loader(evt.target.loader); //This evt targeting MouseEvent 
//u cant target loader from here.
            ob_ldr.startDrag(true);
//also before dragging u need add ur obj to stage.
    }
```

I believe your code should seems like this.

```
var loadedMC:Sprite = new Sprite();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadCompleteFunction);
function onLoadCompleteFunction(e:Event):void
{
    loadedMC = e.target.data;
    this.addChild(loadedMC);
    loadedMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMDown);
    loadedMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMUp);
}
function onMDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.startDrag(true);
}
function onMUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

If u need more help about this. Type under this. I'll try to check this comment :)